# Check the if version of JDK installed on macOS is the correct one

Tags: java, macos, java-8

I have a macbook with latest HighSierra installed and from System Preferences / Java Panel. It says that i have got latest Java version installed: java 8 update 181.

From the "Java" tab of the aforementioned "Java settings" dialog i can see that the version 181 it is referring to is installed in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

If i try to execute that binary (i.e. java -version) i actually get:

```
java version "1.8.0_181" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_181-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)
```

however when i try to launch "java" from a generic prompt or if i try to execute javac i get a different result:

```
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

this latter java is installed in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/

So it seems to me that i have got a jre (181) and a jdk (40) is this correct?

if so, is this the correct setup on mac? i started to wonder when forticlient analyzer showed up a bunch of CVE security issues related to JDK that are fixed in update 181.

Comment: "have got a jre (181) and a jdk (40)" - The "JavaAppletPlugin" (181) is most likely only a JRE. Not sure about the u40 though; could be a JDK or a JRE. It is not uncommon, though often unfortunate (for non-developers), to have multiple versions of Java installed at the same time, each used by some other software (e.g. 64bit vs. 32bit programs).